# Tailable cursor doesn't block on empty collection

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to process notifications as soon as they are added to a MongoDB. For that, there are capped collections that allow the use of tailable cursors. These should block when retrieving the next element until that next element becomes available.

Here's the Go code that I used:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("done.")

    ctx := context.Background()

    collection, err := connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to connect", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("connected.")

    if err := follow(ctx, collection); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to follow", err)
    }
}

func connect(ctx context.Context) (*mongo.Collection, error) {
    // use 3s timeout for connecting
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 3*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    opts := options.Client().
        ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost")
    err := opts.Validate()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    client, err := mongo.NewClient(opts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := client.Connect(ctx); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    db := client.Database("test")
    return db.Collection("example"), nil
}

func follow(ctx context.Context, collection *mongo.Collection) error {
    // create a tailable cursor on the collection
    filter := bson.M{}
    opts := options.Find().
        SetCursorType(options.TailableAwait)
    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, filter, opts)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)

    // load and print documents as they are inserted
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var document bson.M
        if err := cursor.Decode(&document); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Println("loaded document", document)
    }
    return nil
}
```

The MongoDB was set up using Docker, see this Bash script:

```
docker run --rm --detach --name mongodb --publish 27017:27017 mongo:4.2
sleep 2 # Hack: wait for the DB to start up
docker exec mongodb mongo --eval "db.createCollection('example', {capped:true, size: 1000000})"
```

When running the Go program, the following output comes up:

```
connected.
done.
```

Two things are peculiar here: Firstly, I'd expect this to block after connecting, i.e. to never exit. Secondly, there is not even an error!

If you run `docker exec mongodb mongo --eval "db.example.insert({_id:1})"` just to add *some* content to the collection, it changes the program's behaviour. Then, after connecting, it outputs the existing element and then sits there:

```
connected.
loaded document map[_id:1]
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug somewhere else?

Some related questions:

- [Reactive tailable cursor is closed when a mongodb collection is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231139/reactive-tailable-cursor-is-closed-when-a-mongodb-collection-is-empty#54593206)
- [Mongo Tailable Cursor { Error: No More Documents in Tailed Cursor }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437251/mongo-tailable-cursor-error-no-more-documents-in-tailed-cursor/58440141#58440141)
- [Using pymongo tailable cursors dies on empty collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321140/using-pymongo-tailable-cursors-dies-on-empty-collections)

Comment: On another note, this is apparently a known behaviour: [SERVER-13955](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13955)

Comment: Instead of using tailable cursors, have you considered using [changestreams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) instead? They provide the same functionality, but changestreams have more features. I also confirmed that changestreams on an empty capped collection will wait as expected.

Comment: "Created: May 15 2014" -- obviously getting that corner case fixed seems to have zero priority. Thank you very much, @kevinadi, at least I know it's not my bug. Concerning change streams, I haven't considered those yet.